# Is it a good idea to host complex Orchestration/Transformation/Business logic on AEM tier

Tags: architecture, aem

From a design perspective, do you think that it's a good idea to develop complexe business rules, and process orchestration on an AEM tier, for instance:

- call 6 different services (Soap, Rest (XML/JSON)) to retreive customer data and expose it as a servlet to serve it to my Single page application (JS autonomous application) that is hosted on one of my clientlibs.

knowing that this processing doesn't need any AEM capability (no need for content, nor AEM cloud integration, nor personalization,....).

My guess is no, moving this chunk of code to a cheaper server will be wiser.
Even though, form an organizational perspective, it make sense to have all this coherent functionality on the same package, maintained by the same team.

What do you think?

Comment: I think this is rather opinion based. AEM after all uses a Servlet Engine just like Tomcat and Glassfish and nothing prevents you from having your business logic within OSGi bundles. As long as you also use the CMS functionality from AEM, thus already having a paid instance, I personally like to have it within AEM, so only one code base and one deployment mechanism. If it is a standalone single page app, I would go with a Tomcat or similar application server.

Comment: I don't think that the fact that the instance is paid is a factor to make this architectural choice.   Because you ll put much load on a server and you ll need to pay new instances to host a code that doesn't use any AEM

Comment: What I meant is that I wouldn't buy a licence for AEM to just use it as an overpriced application server, but if you already have one it doesn't hurt to run the additional logic on it.

Comment: I m asking my self ( and though the stackoverflowers) the question because i think it hurts. At least for the reasons listed below by shiraz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 4 potential problems caused by placing your code inside the AEM:

- Scalling is more expensive, since you need a paid instance
- Extra cost when New Versions of AEM are introduced
- Extra cost if AEM is discontinued or you need to switch platform
- Developer availability / cost compared with Java developer

Comment: What will be the right minimum to put on aem, at least we must put the logic needed to build our view, retreive a customer data perhapse, .....

Comment: These are valid points, but they might be easily mitigated by using Apache Sling as a fallback. If you aren't using "AEM capability" then AEM and Sling are equivalent.